Looking for C++ Code Coverage Report using CMake and MSVC
I'm looking for a good code coverage solution. Currently I've been using GCOVR and GCC coverage flags to produce detailed code coverage reports when using a C++ program built with CMake in Visual Studio 2022. Obviously, this only works for Linux compilers and am looking for a solution for Windows MSVC compiler that produces similar results of creating a code coverage report.
If I can find a way that this integrations with Visual Studio so I can see the coverage in the program itself (similar to how IntelliJ and Visual Studio (non CMake) normally does code coverage), that'd be perfect.
I've tried using OpenCppCoverage (plugin not available for Visual Studio 2022) and all other options like Lcov, Gcovr, etc. are all for Linux compilers.
